# How to prevent adding same data to SQL from C# program

Tags: c#, sql

This is our code to prevent the same data from being added into SQL from our C# program but only the first same data will not be added in. The remaining ones adds the same data into SQL despite our prevention in our C# program. Can somebody help us troubleshoot?

[image: Our C# code]

Comment: You should post your code to the site directly.

Comment: Adding the code as a picture is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

in order not to duplicate data in database usually you set some constraints to your database. By having a unique field in database you can prevent multiple addition to your db.

Currently you are also fetching data from db to check if it exist already and that creates extra cost, just manipulate the design of db so that it won't accept the same column input twice

Answer (score 0):

Count the value of data that is inserted

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string sql1 = "SELECT COUNT (client_id) FROM client WHERE client_id = '" + txtid.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
        con.Open();
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
       if (temp >0)
        {
//show error message
        }
```

Comment: That's a good way to permit SQL injection attacks. :-( You should be parameterizing your statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the record you want to add, and if it doesn't exists, then add it to the table:

```
SqlConnection _cnt = new SqlConnection();
_cnt.ConnectionString = "Your Connection String";
SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand();
_cmd.Connection = _cnt;
_cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM myTable where Category=@Name";

_cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", string);
_cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = newCatTitle;
_cnt.Open();
var idTemp = _cmd.ExecuteScalar();

_cmd.Dispose();
_cnt.Close();
_cnt.Dispose();
if (idTemp == null)
{
  //Insert into table
}
else
{
  //Message it already exists
}
```

Comment: SQL injection people... `_cmd.Parameters.Add(...)` is not that difficult.

Comment: @Nicarus Actually I tried to do that, but I couldn't find out how!

Comment: Check out the example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Nicarus Ok, I changed it to a parameterized query. Hope I did it right.

Comment: Not quite. You need to use `_cmd` instead of `sqlCommand`. Also, it is good to specify the expected datatype of the parameter value to avoid additional/potential issues.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you'll be writing safer code now. :-)